# Print file names inside a directory (there are subdirectories with files too)

Tags: php

I'm trying to print all files inside of directory **UPLOADS** but there are directories inside of it.
So I need to read inside of all these subdirectories and print file names.
The problem I'm facing is that these subdirectories are being created dinamically, so how can I do this?

This is listing directories too, how can I set it to do not show subdirectories?

```
<?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/*';
   function recursive_glob($pattern){
      $first_files = glob($pattern);
      foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*') as $dir){
         $first_files = array_merge($first_files, recursive_glob($dir.'/'.basename($pattern)));
      }
      return $first_files;
   }
   print_r(recursive_glob($path));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
string system ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )
```

and make a system call with "ls -lR" so recursively